# How to upload newly created sharedAccessPolicy after clearing the existing policy of container defined at azure portal using SDk?

Tags: java, azure, sdk

// In the below method we are downloading the policies of the container into Hashmap

```
static void listSharedAccessPOlicy() throws URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, StorageException {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse (storageConnectionString);
        // Create a blob service client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient ();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference ("containerName");

        //Permission
        BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions ();
        permissions.setPublicAccess (BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);
        container.uploadPermissions (permissions);
        HashMap <String, SharedAccessBlobPolicy> sharedAccessPolicyList1 = container.downloadPermissions ().getSharedAccessPolicies ();
        // pre work of clearing all policies
        HashMap <String, SharedAccessBlobPolicy> sharedAccessPolicyList = permissions.getSharedAccessPolicies ();
        sharedAccessPolicyList.forEach ((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println ("Policyname for key: " + k + v);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you getting an exception when executing this code? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: Yes , you are right . I will edit the question . I was trying to upload new policy and clearing the existing policy .

Comment: Policies can be cleared and added using :-permissions.getSharedAccessPolicies ().clear () and permissions.getSharedAccessPolicies ().put (policyName, writePolicy) , then you will have to upload to container using container.uploadPermissions (permissions);

Comment: I was able to get it  working .

Comment: Please add as an answer and mark it accepted.It will help other who have the same ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below methods can be used for clearing existing policies and creating new one and uploading it.


 public  void clearPolicyAndCreateNewPolicy() {
        log.info ("Getting container for ");
        CloudBlobContainer container = getContainer ();
        log.info ("Deleting existing upload policies of the permissions");
        long nStart = System.nanoTime ();
            BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions ();
            try {
                permissions.setSharedAccessPolicies (container.downloadPermissions ().getSharedAccessPolicies ());
                permissions.getSharedAccessPolicies ().clear ();
                container.uploadPermissions (permissions);
                log.info("Policies all cleared={}", permissions.getSharedAccessPolicies ().isEmpty ());
                String newPolicy = createNewPolicy (container));
                long nTotal = System.nanoTime () - nStart;
                log.info ("Completed invalidateAttachmentToken in ms={} and created new Policy={}", newPolicy, nTotal);
            } catch (StorageException ex) {
                log.info ("Exception occurred during clearUploadPolicy when trying to downloadPermissions of container } and exception={}", ex);
                throw new AzureStorageException ("Not able to perform the request for");
            }
    }

private  String createNewPolicy(CloudBlobContainer container) {
        long nStart = System.nanoTime ();
        BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions ();
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy writePolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy ();
        writePolicy = setBlobAccessPermission(writePolicy);
        writePolicy = setSharedAccessPolicyTimes(writePolicy);
        String policyName = policyNamePrefix + LocalDateTime.now ();;
        permissions.getSharedAccessPolicies ().put (policyName, writePolicy);
        try {
                log.info("Setting the public access to BLOB");
                permissions.setPublicAccess (BLOB);
                container.uploadPermissions (permissions);
                long nTotal = System.nanoTime () - nStart;
                log.info ("Completed createNewPolicy={} in ms={}", policyName, nTotal);

            } catch (StorageException ex) {
            log.info ("Exception occurred during createNewPolicy when trying to uploadPermissions to container  and exception={}", ex);
            throw new AzureStorageException ("Not able to perform the request ");
        }
        return policyName;
    }

    // set the shared access policy start and end LocalDateTime

     private SharedAccessBlobPolicy setSharedAccessPolicyTimes(SharedAccessBlobPolicy writePolicy) {
        //calculate start time
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now ();
        Instant result = now.minusDays (1).minusMinutes (15).atZone (ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant ();
        Date startTime = Date.from (result);
        // calculate Expiration Time for 1 year
        now = LocalDateTime.now ();
        result = now.plusYears (1).atZone (ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant ();
        Date expirationTime = Date.from (result);
        log.info("Setting start time for the new policy");
        writePolicy.setSharedAccessStartTime (startTime);
        log.info("Setting expiry time for the new policy");
        writePolicy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime (expirationTime);
        log.info("Putting the new policy to permissions");
        return writePolicy;
    }

    // set the permissions
    private SharedAccessBlobPolicy setBlobAccessPermission(SharedAccessBlobPolicy writePolicy) {
        writePolicy.setPermissions (EnumSet.of (SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.CREATE, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.LIST));
        return writePolicy;
    }


public CloudBlobContainer getContainer() {}
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse (storageConnectionString);
        // Create a blob service client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient ();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference ("containerName");
return container
}
```